# Is this possible to have negative number of reputations? What happens if you have zero reputations and someone downvotes one of your asked questions?

Tags: discussion

Is this possible to have negative number of reputations?
What happens if you have zero reputations and someone downvotes one of your asked questions?

Comment: Have you tried to read the corresponding help page? (https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation)

Comment: You seem to have managed to just answer this question yourself.

Comment: There is no negative reputation.  If your reputation goes down low and hits zero, you account will get deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this possible to have negative number of reputations?

No. The minimum reputation is 1 and rep won't go below that.

> What happens if you have zero reputations and someone downvotes one of your asked questions?

The vote is shown in the question but it won't alter your reputation.

Note that if you have 1 rep, first you get 2 downvotes and then 1 upvote on your question, your reputation will be 6 (1+5). Since you got downvotes when you're at 1 rep, it won't affect the reputation in future.